# Contribution Summary throws 500 error

Tags: civireport, reports, 500

> Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in
>   /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Summary.php:580

Don't know whether this started with Civi 4.7.19, WP 4.8, or something else -- but now I get this 500 error whenever I try to run a Contribution Summary (Reports / Contribution Reports).

Other Civi summary reports (e.g. Constituent Summary, Event Participants List) run as expected. Other Civi Contribution reports also run as expected. It seems Contribution Summary is our only misbehaving report.

I've disabled all plugins other than CiviCRM and activated Twenty Seventeen theme, but that doesn't stop the 500 error.

> Stack trace: [13-Jun-2017 08:57:17 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in
>   /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Summary.php:580
>   Jun 13, 12:53:49 PHP Warning: Failed to send an email, wp_mail()
>   returned FALSE in /wp-content/plugins/error-log-monitor/Elm/Plugin.php
>   on line 200
>   5 [REDACTED] in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Summary.php
>   on line 580
>   4 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Submit.php(74):
>   CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
>   3 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Summary->postProcess()
>   2 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Summary.php(756):
>   CRM_Report_Form->postProcess()
>   1 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3249): CRM_Report_Form->buildQuery()
>   0 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(2626): CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Summary->groupBy()

It is possible we've had this problem since well before the current Civi and WordPress iterations were released/installed, but hadn't noticed it before because we're still somewhat new to Civi.

I activated debugging and backtracing, but no error info displayed when running Contribution Summary.

I assume Contribution Summary is working fine for everyone else. What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be identical to [CRM-20558](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20558).  Upgrading to 4.7.20 or applying the fix there should solve your problem.  Note that CiviCRM is not tested against PHP 7.1, so you may want to consider using PHP 7.0 instead.

Comment: Thank you Jon -- I'll update to 4.7.20 post-haste and report back later today. I will also ratchet PHP down to 7.0 regardless of whether yesterday's Civi update does the trick.

Comment: While the 4.7.20 upgrade gave me a minor new problem (addressed in another thread, missing indices warning), I'm thrilled to report the Contribution Summary problem was fixed by the upgrade. We're finally able to run the Contribution Summary report again without server errors. Thank you Jon!

Comment: Yeah, I got bit by the missing_indices warning too.  I just hid it for a month; it seems likely that 4.7.21 will have a fix.

Comment: By the way, I switched from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.0 and that may have fixed a different problem. Draft/Unscheduled Mailings and Scheduled & Sent Mailings were both throwing 500 errors every time I tried to load them, but after switching to PHP 7.0, they load fine. Waiting to hear from backend users as to how well it's working now.